# Postgres syntax error after FROM in an UPDATE query

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE user
SET user_status = 'ACCEPTED', last_updated = now()
FROM company
WHERE user.company_id::text = company.company_id::text
AND company.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

The query works fine when ran directly in the database, but I get the following error when it is applied as a flyway migration script:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration XXXXX.sql failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE USER
SET USER_STATUS = 'ACCEPTED', LAST_UPDATED = NOW()
FROM[*] COMPANY
WHERE USER.COMPANY_ID::TEXT = COMPANY.COMPANY_ID::TEXT
AND COMPANY.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'";
```

The error suggests that there is an issue with the `FROM`. However, I've read through the Postgres documentation and looked at example queries and the syntax is the same as what I have used above and appears to be correct.

Flyway Version: `7.0.2`

Postgres Version: `9.6`

Postgres JDBC Driver Version: `42.2.14`

Can anybody help me figure out why I am facing this issue/help me resolve this issue?

Comment: @forpas. No, see [Error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

Comment: What version of Flyway and version of Postgres? Add as update to question. Also read Compatibility section here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) for notes on the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver correct, but the error is incomprehensible for a valid Postgresql statement. This error on the FROM clause would be thrown in MySql (and other) which does not support the UPDATE ... FROM syntax.

Comment: Check your postgres error log, it should have the actual query that flyway used.

Comment: @Bergi this is the actual query that flyway tries to use

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've added the Flyway & Postgres versions

Comment: @Oozeerally You mean the one with the weird `FROM[*]`? And all uppercase identifiers? Well then that looks like a clear bug in Flyway.

Comment: Btw, 42.2.14 is your JDBC version, not your Postgres version, right?

Comment: @Bergi yes Postgres JDBC Driver version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.14 my Postgres version is 9.6 I believe

Comment: I'm going to say this is something you are going to need to bring up with the Flyway folks.

Answer (score 1):

As `user` is a reserved word, it will need to be within quotations:

```
UPDATE "user"
SET user_status = 'ACCEPTED', last_updated = now()
FROM company
WHERE "user".company_id::text = company.company_id::text
AND company.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

(Have tested this and confirmed it resolves the issue)

Comment: the use of "user" was not the issue here, the issue was the use of "from" - also by what means did you test this? Created a script and used flyway to migrate it?

Comment: Indeed: I think the output in the debug around `FROM` is a red herring - When I reproduced the issue I ran flyway with debugging (I am part of the Flyway dev team) and the resultant script to be executed did not expose `FROM` in that format.

Once I reproduced the issue, I renamed the table (to `Test1` and `Test2`) and the problem went away. Returning the table names to their original and using quotes also resolved the issue.